# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Theoretical Computer Science's [3rd moderator election](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4959189067628544/0).

Please also take this time to thank [Suresh Venkat](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/80/suresh-venkat), stepping down after serving as a moderator here since 2010.

Comment: Also... I sincerely apologize for the late announcement; been a hectic week & I let this slip my mind. Big thanks to everyone for their patience during my period of ineptitude!

Comment: Congratulations, Bjørn!  Great to have you serving on the moderator team!

Comment: Thanks @D.W. - excited and honored to be doing so!